# Persistent Jupyter Notebooks and Docker?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I would like to use a Jupyter Notebook within my web app project, mainly for scripting and experimenting with code and data. I am also using docker for my project. This means that when I rebuild a container, I lose my Jupyter notebook. I would like for these notebook to be kept.

Whats the best way of creating a persistent Jupyter Notebook whilst using Docker?

Is there a best practice here? Do I make a virtual environment and run my notebooks separately outside of Docker so that they are not deleted?

Comment: I am not sure how Jupyter notebooks work internally, but maybe you could use docker bind mounts to mount a host folder into your docker container or use other mounting strategies to keep the data between container restarts.

Comment: You probably want to look into [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) or [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: Thanks for that michalk and Dan. I will look into doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers are inherently ephemeral.

To store data, simply create and attach [a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and store the notebook there.

Without more detail on how your docker project is composed, I would default to suggesting using a `docker-compose.yml` file and declaring a `volumes:` block, mounting it to the path the ipynb files are stored.

I'll also note that Jupyter is [already dockerized](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html#jupyter-datascience-notebook) and you may be able to simply compose one of those into your application as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

To conveniently use dockerized jupyter notebook you may want to clone this repo:

https://github.com/vladiuz1/py3-jupyter-docker-compose

Just do this before:

```sh
docker network ls
```

this will give you names of your current networks.

Add the network you need to share with your jupyter to the above repo's docker-compose.yaml like this:

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: <the-name-from-docker-network-ls>
```